# Roth's theorem: contradiction?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, continued-fractions, irrationality-measure

[Roth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem) says that for irrational algebraic number $\alpha$ and $\epsilon>0$, there are finitely many solutions to this:
$$\displaystyle \left|\alpha-\frac pq\right|<\frac 1{q^{2+\epsilon}}$$
but from what I understand from [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)(theorem 5), there are infinitely many convergents of $\alpha$
$$\displaystyle \left|\alpha-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|<\frac {1}{q_nq_{n+1}}<\frac {1}{q_n^2}$$
Since $q_{n+1}>q_n$, we have $\frac {1}{q_nq_{n+1}}=\frac 1{q_n^{2+\epsilon_n}}$ for all $n$, contradicting Roth's theorem.

I probably missed something, but I am not sure what....

Comment: Similar to secant method, the sequence converges as the power of the golden ratio.

Comment: I am not sure to make a connection with $\epsilon$

Comment: $\epsilon_n \to 0$ with $n$ so for a fixed $\epsilon$ in Roth theorem only finite many $q_n$ break the inequality in Roth theorem

Comment: @Conrad, arf...I suspected something like that when I edited my post. I was not interpreting it correctly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Conrad: That's a good answer (and should be an answer rather than just a comment).