# Showing that there exists infinitely many rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ satisfying $|x - p/q|\leq \frac{1}{q^{2+t}}$ for irrational $x$ and $t>0$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, real-numbers, continued-fractions

Let $t>0$ be a fixed parameter and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ be an irrational number. I am trying to show that there exists infinitely many rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ such that $\left|x - \frac{p}{q}\right|\leq \frac{1}{q^{2 + t}}$. I was told that this claim follows almost immediately from contined fractions. Unfortunately I haven't really worked with continued fractions so I am clueless on how I should prove the result. The tricky part seems to be getting the $t$-dependence right to the upperbound.

An alternative approach would be to maybe use a proof by contradiction and the density of rational numbers, although I don't know what you really can say about the denominator of the rational numbers close enough to $x$.

Comment: I once got something similar to this for homework, but it is $<$ instead of $\leq$. Surprisingly, in this case there are only finitely many!

Comment: I am reminded of [Diophantine Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation), @CartesianBear.  (The link points to the relevant Wikipedia page.)

Comment: Note that $1/q^{2+t} < 1/q^2$ for $t > 0$.

Comment: The claim is false.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4040620/roths-theorem-contradiction (algebraic irrational)

Comment: It's easy to disprove for $x = \sqrt{2}$. Indeed, $$\left|\sqrt{2}-\frac{a}{b}\right| = \left|\frac{b\sqrt{2}-a}{b}\right| = \left| \frac{2b^2-a^2}{b(b\sqrt{2}+a)}\right| \ge \frac{1}{b(2b)},$$ where the last inequality follows from the fact that $2b^2-a^2$ is a nonzero integer (nonzero since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational) and from $a \le 2b$ (if $a > 2b$, then $\frac{a}{b}$ is not close to $\sqrt{2}$).

Comment: the result is incorrect; what follows from continued fractions is that $|x - p_n/q_n|\leq \frac{1}{q_n^{2+t_n}}, t_n \to 0$ in general for infinitely many $p_n/q_n$; for fixed $t$ and $x$ algebraic and irrational, Roth's theorem says that there can be only finitely many solutions to $|x - p/q|\leq \frac{1}{q^{2+t}}$ which is very easy to prove in the case of quadratic irrationals like $\sqrt 2$ as noted by @mathworker21

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathworker21 and Conrad gave examples showing that the assertion is false. In fact it is false for almost every $x$ according to Lebesgue measure  (Of course they know this well, one example suffices to refute a general assertion.)  This follows from Khinchin's theorem on metric Diophantine approximation [1], see also [2], [3].
As a special case of this theorem, we find that for every $\epsilon>0$ and almost every real $x$, there are only finitely many rational numbers $p/q$ such that
$|x-p/q|< q^{-2-\epsilon}$. The statement in the previous line just uses the easy direction of Khinchin's theorem, which follows immediately from the first Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

[1] A. Khintchine, "Zur metrischen Theorie der diophantischen Approximationen" Math. Z. , 24 (1926) pp. 706–714

[2][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation#Khinchin's_theorem_on_metric_Diophantine_approximation_and_extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation#Khinchin%27s_theorem_on_metric_Diophantine_approximation_and_extensions)

[3] https://carmamaths.org/pdf/retreat2013/retreat2013-mumtaz_hussain.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the number set in the form of
$\;\mathbf{z=\dfrac m{3q^n}},\;$ where
$$\mathbf{n\in\mathbb N},\quad \mathbf{n>2+t},\quad m\in \mathbb Z.$$

Since the interval between the neighboring points of the building set is less than half of the given interval, then exists two or more points of the set, which belongs to the given interval.
Let the left of obtained point is $\;\dfrac l{3q^n},\;$ then the next one is $\;\dfrac {l+1}{3q^n}.\;$

I.e., obtained a pair of the inner rational points of the given interval.

Calculating the center of the obtained interval, we can get two new intervals.
$$\left(\dfrac{l}{3q^n},\dfrac {2l+1}{6q^n}\right), \left(\dfrac{2l+1}{6q^n}, \dfrac{l+1}{3q^n}\right).$$

Repeating pointed dichotomi procedure for each of the obtained intervals, easily to get arbitrary many rational numbers, which belongs to the given interval.

$\color{green}{\textbf{Appendium.}}$

Continued fractions defined by the formulas
$$x=[q_0;q_1,q_2,\dots]=q_0+\cfrac1{q_1+\cfrac1{q_2+\dots}},$$
where
$$q_0=\lfloor x\rfloor,\quad r_0 = x - q_0,\quad q_{s+1} =\genfrac\lfloor\rfloor{}01{r_s},\quad r_{s+1} = \dfrac1{r_s}-q_{s+1},\quad s=0,1\dots$$

Approximations of the number $x$ of the form $\dfrac{P_s}{Q_s}$ can be calculated using the formulas:
$$P_0=1,\quad Q_0=0,\quad P_1=q_0,\quad Q_1=1,$$
$$P_{s+1}=q_{s+1}P_s+P_{s-1},\quad Q_{s+1}=q_{s+1}Q_s+Q_{s-1},\quad s=1,2,\dots$$

According to the logic of continued fractions (compact approximations of the number $x$), this process should not be infinite. Therefore, calculations should be terminated not only when the fractional part is zero, but also when the specified accuracy is reached.

Comment: not sure what has this to do with the original question (which asks about good rational approximations to some $x$) which is incorrect as stated; rational numbers can never be well approximated as is trivial that fixing a $p/q$ one has $|p/q-r/s| \ge 1/|qs|$ for any fraction $r/s \ne p/q$ so the approximation of $p/q$ by any rational cannot be better than the inverse of the denominator of the approximant (times a constant)

Comment: @Conrad The previous version was not correct. The new version is ready.

Comment: @Conrad To give sufficiently good interval, you can use the continued fractions. They have the suitable property, that two neibour approximations are on the opposite sides of the given point.  Also, your can use modified dihotomy method, which uses the property $\dfrac mn\le\dfrac{m+p}{n+q}\le \dfrac pq.$

Comment: I still do not understand what this has to do with the original problem - the original problem asks for good approximations to some irrational $x$ so $p/q$ is not fixed

Comment: @Conrad Appendium added (translation of my answer on the other site). Waiting to your detailed questions.